# Can we add a maximum time to wait for a process to complete?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to set a timer for a process to be executed? I mean to say if I have a list of Computers, i am running a Invoke command against and one of them is behaving erratic and takes forever to respond, can i set like a timer say for example 2 minutes for the check, if the check isnt complete in 2 mins, process the next computer in the list.

```
Function Rsrt-Service()
{
    $NLAState = (Get-NetConnectionProfile).IPv4Connectivity

    "Access type : $NLAState"
    if($NLAState -ne 'Internet')
        {
            "Access type : $NLAState"
            "restarting NLA service"
            #Restart-Service  -Name NlaSvc  -Force
            Out-file -FilePath C:\test\abc.txt -Append

        }

}   
foreach ($server in $serversnames)
    {
     Invoke-Command -ComputerName $($server.DNSName)  -ScriptBlock 
     ${Function:Rsrt-Service} -ArgumentList $($server.DNSName) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps [Wait-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job?view=powershell-6) or [Wait-Action](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Wait-Action/1.0/Content/Wait-Action.ps1) can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Start-Process` cmdlet to start the process (you didn't mention this), you could wait for a timeout period of time using something like this:

```
$theProcess = Start-Process -FilePath $runThis -ArgumentList $takeTheseArguments -PassThru

# create a variable to capture the timeout event
$errTimedOut = $null

# wait for a maximum of seconds. After this, $errTimedOut is $null when the process started OK
$theProcess | Wait-Process -Timeout 120 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errTimedOut

if ($errTimedOut) {
    # do something here to let you know the process timed out
    Write-Warning "Process did not start"
}
```

Comment: Hi Theo, Thanks for reply. I am not using Start-Process, but something like the code that i have added now to the main question (should have done it in the first place).